# LiveData Observer for realmresults not getting triggered first time

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, realm, android-livedata

I am going through [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#) and trying to implement MVVM and LiveData in one of my apps. I am using realm and I am using [this](https://medium.com/@eric.maxwell/how-to-use-livedata-with-realm-3e57958b5aa1) to create a RealmLiveData as shown below

```
class RealmLiveData<T : RealmModel>(private val results: RealmResults<T>) : MutableLiveData<RealmResults<T>>() {
private val listener = RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> { results -> value = results }
override fun onActive() {
    results.addChangeListener(listener)
}

override fun onInactive() {
    results.removeChangeListener(listener)
}
}
```

This how I am updating the list to recyclerview

```
var mList:ArrayList<Notes> = ArrayList()

lateinit var historyViewModel: HistoryViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false)
    mRCview = view.findViewById(R.id.list)
    historyViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(HistoryViewModel::class.java)

    // this is how I observe
    historyViewModel.getList().observe(this, Observer{
        (mRCview.adapter as MyHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter).setData(it)
    })

    with(mRCview) {
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mContext)
        mList = ArrayList()
        adapter = MyHistoryRecyclerViewAdapter(
            mContext as OnListFragmentInteractionListener
        )
    }
    return view
}
```

This is how I get the data in my repository class

```
class HistoryRepository {

fun getHistory(): RealmLiveData<Notes> {
    val realmInstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
    val realmResults = realmInstance
        .where(Notes::class.java)
        .findAll()
        .sort("lastUpdatedTimeStamp", Sort.DESCENDING)
    return realmResults.asLiveData()
}

fun <T:RealmModel> RealmResults<T>.asLiveData() = RealmLiveData(this)
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the ViewModel

```
class HistoryViewModel: ViewModel() {

val repository = HistoryRepository()

fun getList(): RealmLiveData<Notes> {
    return repository.getHistory()
}
}
```

The issue is that the observer is not getting triggered **for the first time.** If I update the realmresult, the live data update gets invoked and updates my list. Please let me know how I can fix the issue.

Comment: Could you please post the code for `HistoryViewModel`?

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu I have added the ViewModel

Comment: You are adding `results.addChangeListener(listener)` in `onAdded()`. Since the listener is added after the first observer is attached to the LiveData, the existing data on realm will not be triggered. 

This is my guess, haven't used Realm.

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu ok..that seems to be the issue. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: After adding the listener in `onActive()`  you need to trigger the `onChange()` of the listener once to notify the added Observer of the existing data. 
I have not used Realm so I cant help you with the best implementation of this approach.

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu I called listener.onChange(results) after adding the changelistener. If you can add it as an answer I will accept it thanks Btw.. and sorry for my ignorance

Comment: @free_style What is onAdded, I don't see it in your code? (I have exactly the same issue at the same time )

Comment: @unludo what a coincidence :).  In the first piece of code, in onActive callback, after realmResults.onChange(results) i called listener.onChange(results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to notify the Observer of the existing data. When the first Observer registers to `historyViewModel.getList()` you are registering the realm callback. At this point we need to trigger a change just to notify this Observer of the existing data.

Something like

```
class RealmLiveData<T : RealmModel>(private val results: RealmResults<T>) : MutableLiveData<RealmResults<T>>() {
private val listener = RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<T>> { results -> value = results }
override fun onActive() {
    results.addChangeListener(listener)
    listener.onChange(results) // notify the added Observer of the existing data.
}

override fun onInactive() {
    results.removeChangeListener(listener)
}
}
```